# Ensure API consistency without the need for a trait import

Tags: rust, traits

I have a bunch of structs `A`, `B`, and `C` that somewhat belong to the same category from the user's point of view. All of them should have a few methods in common, let's say `fn add_message(&mut self, msg: String)` and `fn set_data(&mut self, data: Vec<u8>)`. The only goal is to ensure API consistency of struct specific methods that should always be in scope when the struct is in scope.

Is it possible to have a crate-internal compile time check that ensure the structs `A`, `B`, and `C` all have `add_message` and `set_data` of the same signature without exposing a public trait that the caller needs to import?

Comment: What's the issue with needing to import traits? That said, I guess the _easiest_ way would be to create test cases, and just use a CI to always check those

Comment: @vallentin the mental burden on the user to learn about the trait as well as namespace pollution.

Comment: Also the compile errors you get when importing the type and try to use one of the functions

Comment: What compile errors? To each their own of course, but personally I wouldn't complicate my library, just to satisfy beginners. Knowing to import traits isn't a huge ask, and people don't get far in Rust, if they want to avoid traits. However, like I said before, I think the easiest way is to use test cases, to ensure the duplicate `add_message` and `set_data` aren't broken.

Comment: You could move a constructor method for your struct to trait, thus making it impossible to not import the required trait.

Comment: @vallentin When the user imports `B`, they get a compile error when trying to use `B::add_message` and `B::set_data` even if the trait is implemented in the same file where `B` is defined – which is a feature, I know. The issue I see with unit tests is they don't ensure the signatures remain the same for A, B and C when things change over time.

Comment: What @IvanC would be an option. I still don't see that as an issue, because then you go to the docs, and search `add_message` and you'll immediately see it's from a trait. I don't understand the problem with tests either. If you have a test that performs `x.add_message(String::from("Hello"));`, then if you change `add_message` for `B` to `add_message(&self, msg: Message)`, then how doesn't the tests catch that?

Comment: @vallentin My audience is not necessarily Rust power users and I try to avoid symbols that do too little to justify their weight (in terms of education and documentation). When I change the signature of `A::add_message` and adapt the unit tests, it is to easy to forget doing the same for B and C.

Comment: Then you could add a comment to remember. However, breaking and then modifying existing test cases, that should already be done extremely carefully. Because it means your library just introduced a breaking change. The funny thing right now, is that if you break the function signature, then your (beginner) users are already going to be confused and annoyed after updating. :)